# String in switch java

Tags: java, java-7

```
switch(title)
   {
    case "Return":
          returnBooks();
          break;
  }
```

strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6, use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch

So, I have already installed JDK7, Why compiler show this message and giving an error while on compiling?

I am using NetBeans

Comment: Are you compiling directly form the terminal or are you using an IDE ?

Comment: Do you have more than one JRE installed on your system? If so, have you specified JDK7 as your JRE of choice? I suspect from the error message you're getting that your system is using JRE/JDK6 even if JDK7 is installed.

Comment: Listen to Matt below - you have to use the `-source 7` flag.

Comment: you probably need to configure on the project properties or build configuration panel to set that extra parameter everyone is talking about

Comment: I appreciate all comments answer but I don't need probably as all users are doing, I required the exact answer which hit the point not surrounding that is why I consult the forum. No one telling in this ways that you are using Ntbeans and go to the Properties>Libraries etc....

Answer (score 16):

I hate to say it, but: **read the darn error message.** It tells you ***exactly*** what the problem is.

You are compiling in Java 6 mode, not compiling in Java 7 mode. If you're using `javac` that comes with JDK 7, as the error message says, use the `-source 7` flag:

```
> javac -source 7 {stuff here}
```

Comment: Common sense, people, _common sense_... I'm going to bed.

Comment: I think you dont have to be all guru about it... the guy says he has only jdk7 installed ..then why the hell he should give that stupid flag!

Comment: Telling people to use their common sense is "guru"?  Crikey Bruce, I never knew that that advice was so profound!

Comment: @ChingPing the guy says that he already installed JDK7, he not says he has only jdk7 installed.

Answer (score 10):

Two key points from the user query:

1. Already installed JDK7;and
2. Using Netbeans

So, netbeans came with two package:

1. With JDK

Means when install the Netbeans 7 it automatically install JDK 7 and set JDK 7 as Default Library.

1. Without JDK

On the installation of NetBeans 7, it found JDK in the system, and if found it automatically configure the path of library as well, but show you information about the path and version of JDK7.

All of users try to give the correct answer of this query, but no one is in position to answer in the correct way as the user required because user using the Netbeans as well.

With continue the edit version of **Hemal Pandya**, one thing more is required to configure, which is that

```
RightClick on  Project > properties > and in the categories option select > source. see the  
**Hemal Pandya** edit version to look at image, the source option is available above the   
Libraries option.
```

And

```
then select **Source/Binary Format** form bottom and set it to JDK 7 (= 1.7). this is the exact solution
of user's post and I am 100% sure now String in swich will work
```

Comment: Thanks Both_FM , you are really Genius! Now my problem has resolved

Answer (score 4):

In NetBeans, go to the properties of the project and change the java platform to java 7 in libraries

Comment: Java platform is already set to Java 7 (Default)in libraries!

Comment: http://bits.netbeans.org/media/register-jdk7.swf Check this link I have already done this activity but still compiler error!

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution:
If you are using Netbeans 7.1 (even, 7.0), just you have to follow this:
Right Click on Project -> Properties -> Sources -> (On the bottom) Source/Binary Format

Just select JDK 7, and that's all, you can then use strings in switch!

Answer (score 1):

I do not use NetBeans but there seems to be a compliance switch that has defaulted to 1.6. You will have to find that switch and set it to 7, as others have pointed out.

EDIT: I found I found netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-jdk. You seem to have done the second step of registering jdk. But maybe it is not the default? Follow the instructions to To switch the target JDK of a standard project. Looking at images it seems to be in this dialog:

[image]

Comment: bits.netbeans.org/media/register-jdk7.swf Check this link I have already done this activity but still compiler error!

Comment: Did you also make it default? Or there must be a **per project** setting

Comment: I found http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-jdk. You seem to have done the second step of registering jdk. But maybe it is not the default? Follow the instructions to **To switch the target JDK of a standard project:**